# Windows Phone App crashes when using NavigationService.GoBack() too soon

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, dispatcher, navigationservice

Even though `NavigationService.CanGoBack` returns `True`, `NavigationService.GoBack()` throws me these exceptions :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
```

**This happens systematically on two case, while the third works fine :**

- Crashes if I call `NavigationService.GoBack()` **in `OnNavigatedTo()`**
- Crashes If I call `NavigationService.GoBack()` **as a result of `WebException` thrown in my `HTTPWebRequest`** when Internet is not available [1]
- Works fine if Internet is available and I call `NavigationService.GoBack()` when my `HTTPWebRequest` got results, parsed them, and displayed them.

My theory is that I can't call `GoBack()` too soon after navigating from a page to another... My question : **How can I programatically go back up the navigation stack when an `HTTPWebRequest` fails to load ?**

Edit : I've decided to do it another way, but I think my problems might be due to navigation animations and the Windows Phone C# Toolkit (I use Feb 2011 edition)

---

[1] Details of my code on case 2 :

I have a simple `HTTPWebRequest`. My callback does this, and my app crashes when in Airplane Mode. The line `NavigationService.GoBack()` is responsible, even though `NavigationService.CanGoBack` returns `true`.

```
        try
        {
            response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            });
        }
```

I tried using `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` also.

Comment: My first guess was that you have to make sure to execute NavigationService.GoBack() on the UI thread, but that's what you are apparently doing... Have you checked if the page that you are navigation back to is being loaded? Maybe that page if causing these exceptions?

Comment: You're right. If I do `NavigationService.GoBack()` instead of the `HTTPWebRequest` then GoBack() in a catch I have the same exceptions ! But I don't even get to my `OnNavigatedTo` ! If I have Internet, do the web request and call GoBack on the main thread once the request is successful, it work though. My guess is the GoBack fails if it happens too soon ? I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `WebClient client = new WebClient();`, then use `client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("request_url"));` to make your request and subscribe to the `client.DownloadStringCompleted` event to receive your data when the request is completed. After parsing the data, in the event handler you can then call `NavigationService.GoBack();` or go to whichever page you want.

Also, if you try to do something in the `OnNavigatedTo` event and run into trouble you could try using the `OnNavigatingFrom` instead (on the previous page ofc), cancel the navigation `e.Cancel = true;`, do your thing as in make the request and stuff, then get the application frame and navigate to `e.Uri` (basically continuing the navigation you previously cancelled).

Altho this second might represent a solution as well, I think the first one is better as it does all the work async thus not blocking your UI thread. This is what I generally use in my apps. Hope it helps.